# Why does NextJS fail to serialize an object created from a TypeScript class?

Tags: typescript, next.js

In the following code, I am creating an object from a TypeScript class and try to pass it to a NextJS page component via `getStaticProps`. Unfortunately, it fails with the following error:

```
Error: Error serializing `.obj` returned from `getStaticProps` in "/repro".
Reason: `object` ("[object Object]") cannot be serialized as JSON.
Please only return JSON serializable data types.
```

```tsx
import { GetStaticProps, InferGetStaticPropsType } from "next"

const ReproPage = ({ obj }: InferGetStaticPropsType<typeof getStaticProps>) => {
  return <div>{obj.name}</div>
}

export default ReproPage

export const getStaticProps: GetStaticProps<{
  obj: A
}> = async () => {
  return {
    props: {
      obj: new A("hello"),
    },
    revalidate: 10,
  }
}

class A {
  constructor(public name: string) {}
}
```

When I do the following:

```tsx
import util from "util"

console.log(util.inspect(new A("hello", true, 10, true))
```

I get:

```
A { name: 'hello' }
```

It doesn't seem there is something not serializable like a function in the object. I don't understand why this object can't be serialized.

A workaround is doing:

```tsx
export const getStaticProps: GetStaticProps<{
  obj: A
}> = async () => {
  return {
    props: {
      obj:  { ...new A("hello") } as A,
    },
    revalidate: 10,
  }
}
```

But it looks a little silly.

I also tried to add a `toString` and `toJSON` methods to the class, but it doesn't seem the serialization process uses these methods.

Anyone knows what I can do to help NextJS to serialize this object?

Comment: _"I also tried to add a `toString` and `toJSON` methods to the class"_ - you would have to call those functions yourself before passing the value in the return statement, i.e. `props: { obj: new A("hello").toJSON() }`.

Comment: Thanks for helping, this does the trick. But I still don't understand why NextJS can't serialize the object by default.

Comment: The following thread might shed some light on that: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/11993.